# Why $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\alpha})\neq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\beta})$ if $\sqrt{\alpha \beta} \notin \mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, rational-numbers

I was wondering why if we take $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\sqrt{\alpha \beta} \notin \mathbb{Q}$, then we have that the field extensions $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\alpha})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\beta})$ are not the same. And also, it is an iff statement? It is possible to generalise it?

Comment: If $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\alpha})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\beta})$, then there are $r,s\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\sqrt{\alpha}=r+s\sqrt{\beta}$. If $s=0$, then $\sqrt{\alpha},\sqrt{\beta}\in\mathbb{Q}$. Assum $s\neq0$. Passing the roots to one side and squaring you get that $\sqrt{\alpha\beta}=\frac{\alpha+\beta-r^2}{2s}\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: If $\sqrt{\alpha\beta}\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $\sqrt{\alpha}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\beta}}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\beta})$ and similarly swapping the roles of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.